# Multiple heroku.yml in a single repository, is it possible?

Tags: heroku

My application has two distinct parts, a frontend app (a node server) and a backend API (written in Swift). Ideally I'd like for both to live inside a single repository, and the same Heroku pipeline. However that doesn't seem to be compatible with Heroku container deploys, as the heroku.yml must reside in the root directory. I need two separate heroku.yml files, with the ability to specify which to use when deploying.

I'm confused as to how a Heroku pipeline would have any more than one app per environment? The git repository is configured at the pipeline level, so whenever I push changes, it's going to use the root heroku.yml, regardless of which remote/app I push to.

Answer (score -1):

That's correct, the `heroku.yml` defines multiple Docker images for the same application. In your case you can place the `heroku.yml` in the root, then have one folder per service.

The `heroku.yml` will define where to find the Docker file

```
web: folder1/Dockerfile
worker: folder2/Dockerfile
```

You can see a full example [here](https://medium.com/geekculture/multiple-docker-images-on-heroku-3270ed31f2e5).

BTW it is only possible to deploy a Web dyno (frontend) so your worker (API) cannot accept HTTP requests (they could communicate via a queue for example).  If you want to keep the current architecture you cannot use `heroku.yml` but instead create 2 Heroku apps (each one with its own Docker file).